# Phantomjs not rendering Angular + Websockets page

Tags: angularjs, websocket, phantomjs, prerender

Running into a situation where some complex pages (complex in terms of nested views) are not rendering at all in Phantom (using http://prerender.io) I'm using:

Phantom 1.9.8
Websocket 1.2.0
Angular 1.3.1

I think it's an issue with websockets because the pages I've tested that don't rely on sockets seem to load fine but when I tried forcing `'transports': ['polling']` it still didn't load over ajax.

I'm wondering if there's a headless browser that can overcome any websocket roadblocks

Comment: PhantomJS 1.x doesn't support websockets.

Comment: I've seen that but the only way I can find to get Phantom 2.x is by building it from source which I then don't have a way to connect to my npm package.

Comment: Any browser can be made headless with xvfb. This question is essentially asking for a tool which is off-topic for StackOverflow. [softwarerecs.se] is the appropriate place to ask this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to compile PhantomJS 2.0 since 1.9.8 does not support websockets. We are running a compiled PhantomJS 2.0 in production for https://prerender.io so you could try just using our production server pointing to a public staging server of yours.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I couldn't get 2.0 hooked up in my test env and I settled with refactoring my codebase to use AJAX calls if called by Prerender and that did the trick.

Comment: I can confirm that prerender.io works with WebSockets. Happy customer.